# home/end buttons on microsoft natural keyboard 4000 and apple snow

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard

is there a way that my apple snow will fully support Microsoft natural keyboard 4000 ? i need that 'home' and 'end' will go to the beginning/end of the line as it's supposed to.

someone recommended me to use Start -> left/right buttons but these also don't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcuts for going to the beginning/end of a line are a little different on a Macintosh... I know because it took me a little while to adjust to it myself when I switched!

Just so we're on the same page, the "Start" button (the one with the Windows symbol on it) on a regular keyboard is the same as the "Command" or "Apple" key on an Apple-made keyboard. (also note that on an Apple-made keyboard, the Command/Windows key and the Alt key are switched around). The symbol for it is a square with a loop on each corner.

Unfortunately, even with Snow Leopard's nice new keyboard shortcut editor, there is not a user-friendly way to change the behavior of the home/end keys.

I found a tutorial on how to change this, but it didn't work for me. The tutorial teaches you how to create a preference file, which changes keyboard shortcuts for only the current user (i.e.: you have to re-create the file for other users of the same computer; and it won't work on the login screen). You can find it at http://www.starryhope.com/tech/2006/mac-os-x-home-and-end-keys/.

They apparently also have a utility to do this in a more user-friendly way, but it doesn't work with every program and I don't know the author, so install the utility at your own risk.

---

Most of the rest of the shortcuts (save, cut, copy, paste) are very similar to the ones in Windows; but you have to hold the "Command" key instead of the "Control" key. Just last week, I discovered a setting in the Snow Leopard keyboard preferences that let you switch the control/command keys around if you feel more comfortable that way.

If you want to do this, go to System Preferences, click "Keyboard", and choose "Modifier Keys" from the "Keyboard" tab. Select the keyboard you want to apply these changes to, and  change the keys using the drop-downs below. Note that these changes are only applied to the keyboard you selected, and only works when you are logged in (i.e.: you have to re-set this for other users of the same computer; and it won't work on the login screen).

---

If you want to learn the default Macintosh shortcuts, they are as follows:

- To go to the beginning of a line, hold down the Command (or "Windows") key and press the left arrow.
- To go to the end, hold down the Command key and press the right arrow.

Similar to Windows, holding the Shift key while pressing Command-Left or Command-Right selects from the current position to the beginning or end of line respectively.

Comment: Another program that I found was DoubleCommand <http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/>. It modifies the keyboard behaviour with a kernel extension; but can be configured on a per-user basis. They're still working on properly compatibility with Snow Leopard. Again, install it at your own risk.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: another program from that same url you provided: http://www.starryhope.com/tech/apple/2006/keyfixer/